Apache2.4, How to disable OCSP?
Am running Apache 2.4 on Windows, with Let's Encrypt certification. Now, in July this year, Let's Encrypt announced intention to remove OCSP Service.  Am using mod_md and hppt-01 challenge for automatic certification update, that makes things complex.
[Situation]

Checked httpd-ssl.conf and found that "SSLUseStapling" line was commented out, that means OCSP is OFF as default. Right?
Cannot find "SSLOCSPEnable" directive in httpd.conf, httpd-ssl.conf, or openssl.cnf. The default must be OFF.
Ran SSL Labs SSL test. The result is "OCSP stapling: Yes" !!!
Apache documentation about mod_md says "OCSP Stapling is a necessary component for any https: site".

[Question]

How can I disable OCSP?
How will certification update be handled after disabling?

